# Trying to create a link with WebApi not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

In my project I need to create a link with parameters, so I was doing like this :

```
var link = new Uri(Url.Link("GetUser", new { id = 1 }));

static List<Students> std = new List<Students>()
{
    new Students(){id = 1, Nome = "Nathiel"},
    new Students() {id = 2, Nome = "Barros"}
};
```

And them the method that would receive the id :

```
[Route("{id:int}",Name = "GetUser")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get(int id)
{
    var u = std.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == id);

    var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
    response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, u);

    var task = new TaskCompletionSource<HttpResponseMessage>();
    task.SetResult(response);
    return await task.Task;
}
```

The problem is, the URL is not concatenate the second Route, "GetUser", and is coming like this : `"http://localhost:52494/api/v1/Register/1"`.

Comment: What is the URL you're expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the route prefix is `api/v1/Register`

```
[RoutePrefix("api/v1/Register")]
public class RegisterController : ApiController {
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{id:int}",Name = "GetUser")] //Matches GET api/v1/Register/1
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(int id) {
        //...code removed for brevity
    }
}
```

then that is by design.

The Route Name is used to identify the route template to use when generating the route.

If you want `GetUser` in the URL then include it in the route template

```
[RoutePrefix("api/v1/Register")]
public class RegisterController : ApiController {
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetUser/{id:int}",Name = "GetUser")] //Matches GET api/v1/Register/GetUser/1
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(int id) {
        //...code removed for brevity
    }
}
```

Comment: Got it! thanks,that was my problem, the `Name` property is to identify the actual Route.